# Event for input change through script (.value)

Tags: javascript

Is there an event which triggers for every change (both user and script). I've found a stack question from 2009, where it was suggested to use DOM Mutation.

Did the human race invent any better solution for this?

P.S. Some code for people, who can't imagine the situation.

```js
input = document.getElementById('input');
output = document.getElementById('output');
submit = document.getElementById('submit');

input.addEventListener('input', function(){
 output.innerText = "It works!";
})

submit.onclick = function(){
 input.value = 'Hello!';
}

//Firstly try to Submit. Oh look! Nothing happened!
//Now try to write anything. Hmm, it works!
```

```html
<input id="input">
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: What kind of _change_ are you referring to?

Comment: No, I don't think there's any event triggered when the value of an input is changed by Javascript. You need to change the code that performs the change to call your function.

Comment: @tmslnz Here's the code.

Answer (score 0):

*Humanity is in the process of dropping Mutation events*

You can observe for a variety of changes in the DOM via the `MutationObserver` class.

Straight from MDN for convenience (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
// select the target node
var target = document.getElementById('SOME-ELEMENT-ID');
 
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});
 
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
 
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
 
// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```